# Loading Dynamic Touchscroller page Externally

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, external

Greetings am trying to load a dynamically generated (PHP) Touchscroller page into an index.html file for a Phonegap app.

Thomas Kahn's cool jQuery plug-in code is here:
http://smoothtouchscroll.com/

In addition it loads these resources, some of which are on my server:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothTouchScroll.css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="js/jquery.kinetic.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="js/jquery.smoothTouchScroll.min.js">
```

Have tried jQuery Load and Get methods and the vanilla javascript XMLHttp response-innerHTML request, but the images come back disjointed and there is no scrolling effect.

Going to the dynamically generated PHP page directly (echoing full code with resources) generates a working Touchscroller, so I know the loaded page works, which leaves me thinking it may be a timing issue.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Question solved!  I basically answered my own question, it was in fact a timing thing and what I needed to do was callback the touchscroll function after a successful response, like this:

```
 $("#touchScroller").load("sts.php", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){

 if(statusTxt == "success"){
 $(function(){
 $("#touchScroller").smoothTouchScroll({ continuousScrolling: true });
 });
 }

 });
```

I swear, sometimes putting your question into words helps clarify your thoughts and find an answer.  Hope this helps other Phonegappers like myself that have to integrate dynamic (PHP+jQuery) content into a regular html page.